# error when adding tableadapter to dataset

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a winforms application in Vb.net
when i try to add a tableadapter to an existing dataset I am receiving the error:

> Failed to open a connection to the database. 
>   "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ###Filelocation### failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." Check the connection and try again.

This same dataset has 2 other tableadapters using the same dataconnection (as I am selecting the already existing dataconnection) which work fine
this connection is using application connection strings:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;Integrated 
server=localhost;user id=root;password=password;database=testuser;persistsecurityinfo=True
```

this error pops up every time I select the dataconnector on the first window that pops up.
Why is this happening

additional info:
The other 2 tableadapters were added to this dataset using a different computer
this is for a mysql connection

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5b1c8dc4-6252-4c01-948b-d40af3edd3fd/connecting-to-database-made-from-sql-management-studio?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: this did not solve my problem

Comment: Can you attach the database manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post on the MSDN forum:

[An attempt to attach an auto-named database ....\aspnetdb.mdf failed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fafe818f-8aa3-46cd-bb69-55e540e7a62e/an-attempt-to-attach-an-autonamed-database-aspnetdbmdf-failed?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

One of the suggestions is as Mr. [DonBoitnott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633308/donboitnott) correctly says, add `User Instance=True;`. *But*, there's also another suggestion posted by [Luke A](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/luke%20a/?ws=usercard-mini).

> *"For the record, not one single error message given to me during the course of trying to fix this was relevant to the actual problem. Upon first receiving "An attempt to attached an auto-named database..." I looked online for every suggestion I could find: use an absolute path to the MDF, reorder TCP/IP and named pipes in the server configuration, disable/enable UserInstance (depending on where you looked), change security settings, reconfigure authentication, give specific login credentials.*
>
> *None of these worked. All of these led to different vague/ambiguous error messages, which led to another problem which required a solution which led back to the original error message... an endless loop of problems, completely unrelated to what was actually wrong.*
>
> _Also, posts about setting correct permissions on the App_Data folder are deceptive, as they imply the default permissions were not sufficient for SQL Express (in fact, they are). The whole point of this VS environment is that you can develop a web application and plop it right onto an IIS/SQLExpress setup and have it work. This makes the applications more portable (within IIS, of course) and secure. Of course, everything configuration-related has been obfuscated enough to make it several orders of magnitude more difficult than it has to be."_

**So:** Try prepend `Initial Catalog=uniquenamehere` to your connection string.

Though he says *`"... where 'uniquenamehere' is some name for your project."`*, try replacing `uniquenamehere` with the actual name of the database where the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

the file is a .mdf file so it is a mssql file

my guess would be that as you stated you are using mysql the connection string has to be a tad different and therefore the Dataset can't connect to Mysql

Comment: I would agree with you however - this exact connection string is currently working on the same dataset for 2 other tableadapters connecting to this mysql db

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `User Instance=True;` to the connection string.